# How to prevent '#' be converted to '%23' in Next/Link?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I was trying to use `#{id}` to move user to an element with the given id, but the href somehow always get its hashtag converted into %23. Is there a way to prevent this?

UPDATE: This is one of the components that have that issue. When the `item.href` contains "#", it would become `%23` on rendering. It was used in a drop down menu component.

```js
export interface NavItemType {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  href: string | "#" | "/#";
  toId?: string;
  targetBlank?: boolean;
  children?: NavItemType[];
  megaMenu?: MegamenuItem[];
  type?: "dropdown" | "megaMenu" | "none";
}
```

```js
  const renderDropdownMenuNavlink = (item: NavItemType) => {
    return (
      <Link
        href={{
          pathname: item.href || undefined,
        }}
        passHref
      >
        <a
          target={item.targetBlank ? "_blank" : undefined}
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
          className={
            "flex items-center font-normal text-neutral-6000 dark:text-neutral-400 py-2 px-4 rounded-md hover:text-neutral-700 hover:bg-neutral-100 dark:hover:bg-neutral-800 dark:hover:text-neutral-200" +
            (router.pathname === item.href ? "!font-medium !text-neutral-900 dark:!text-neutral-100" : "")
          }
        >
          {item.name}
          {item.type && (
            <ChevronDownIcon
              className="ml-2 h-4 w-4 text-neutral-500"
              aria-hidden="true"
            />
          )}
        </a>
      </Link>
    );
  };
```

Comment: something causes [uri](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) or [uri component](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) encoding. that might be either in library you are using or browser extensions/plugins you have installed, or some other software that has access either your browser's address bar or uri sdk.

Comment: Not related to your issue, but type `string | "#" | "/#"` can just be written as `string`, because any specific example of a string is already a subtype of `string`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NextJS uses the native `UrlObject` from `node` or `browser` if not SSR.
`pahname` is specifically used for path name so anything not accepted there will be encoded, what you might need is `hash` but you might also be able to use your `item.href` directly into `href` prop of your `Link`

[More info here](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#urlhash)

Answer (score 0):

As @Marlom said, your url is encoded when using #, resulting with a %23 in your url. My solution is to use the **hash** property of the next/link component. Maybe parsing it before if your href contains the #? My solution would be :

```
<Link href={{ pathname: props.href, hash: props.hash }}>
</Link>
```

With your example (and the parsing) :

```
  const renderDropdownMenuNavlink = (item: NavItemType) => {
    const [pathname, hash] = item.href.split("#");
    return (
      <Link
        href={{
          pathname: pathname || undefined,
          hash: hash,
        }}
      >
        <a
          target={item.targetBlank ? "_blank" : undefined}
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
          className={
            "flex items-center font-normal text-neutral-6000 dark:text-neutral-400 py-2 px-4 rounded-md hover:text-neutral-700 hover:bg-neutral-100 dark:hover:bg-neutral-800 dark:hover:text-neutral-200" +
            (router.pathname === item.href ? "!font-medium !text-neutral-900 dark:!text-neutral-100" : "")
          }
        >
          {item.name}
          {item.type && (
            <ChevronDownIcon
              className="ml-2 h-4 w-4 text-neutral-500"
              aria-hidden="true"
            />
          )}
        </a>
      </Link>
    );
  };
```

Or, if it is possible, adding a hash property to your NavItemType interface so you don't have to parse it :

```
export interface NavItemType {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  href: string;
  hash: string;
  toId?: string;
  targetBlank?: boolean;
  children?: NavItemType[];
  megaMenu?: MegamenuItem[];
  type?: "dropdown" | "megaMenu" | "none";
}
```